# How to send unacked messages to DLX after TTL?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I have rabbit queue `my_queue` which is configured with [DLX](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) sending messages to `my_queue_dlx`. A test with [message-ttl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) works as expected. A message which stays in a queue for ttl and later moved to DLX if it is not consumed.

I have a PHP consumer with [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) which consumes a message and after a successful handling sends `ack`.

Problem: It may happen that this PHP consumer will be killed by OS or PHP runtime itself because of high memory usage and this is unknown in advance before handling a message. I basically want to have a unacknowledged message handled by PHP consumer and if it got killed because of OOM, the message would expire and go to DLX.

**Is there a way to set unacknowledged message timeout/expiration, so it would go to DLX?**

Current `my_queue` example:

```
my_queue:
    x-queue-mode: lazy
    x-max-length-bytes: 53687091200 # limited to 50GBs
    x-overflow: drop-head
    x-dead-letter-exchange: some_exchange
    x-dead-letter-routing-key: my_queue_dlx
```

Comment: The TTL _should_ be effective whether or not the message is delivered to a consumer. Are you saying that a delivered, but un-ACK-ed message just sits in limbo forever? You should also post the queue declaration and DLX config so that people can actually offer advice instead of simple speculation.

Comment: @Sammitch the TTL is effective whether or not the message is delivered to a consumer. I don't want that messages would expire while kept in a queue without them being picked by consumers. I want "expiration timer started" once a message is picked by a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`consumer_timeout`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) rather than TTL.

Though this will likely cause messages to be re-delivered until they either hit a configured TTL or are otherwise rejected by a consumer. This *would* fit your case of "consumer gone away", but not necessarily a "poison message" scenario. I would suggest using both TTL for an overall deadline for message processing and `consumer_timeout` for the concern of an individual consumer.

If you want to fix a message to a certain number of deliveries, then I believe that *that* setting is only available via [Quorum Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html)' [`delivery-limit`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#poison-message-handling) setting. However Quorum Queues have their own set of [unique caveats](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#use-cases), as opposed to "classic" queues.

TLDR:

- **TTL**: "Messages must be handled within this time frame, one way or another."
- **consumer_timeout**: "The consumer must handle messages within this amount of time."
- **delivery-limit**: "Only attempt X deliveries of any given message in this queue, with some additional caveats."